# AngularFire2 FirebaseListObservable across multiple (routed) components

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I'm trying to build a social platform for our sailing club with Angular2/Firebase/AngularFire. The first module is to allow users to search for a club member by several criteria (filters), up to around 10 or so.
This in itself meant I had to search around a lot for a technique to overcome the lack of query capabilities in Firebase.
I created a component to manage the filters, with a child routed component to hold a list of the successfully filtered members, then ultimately a click handler to then route to the members profile itself.
Filter component is like this:
HTML template contains several radios to all selection of filters, example: gender. When clicked, this fires the onFilter method.

**Filter Component**

```
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="genderRadios" id="genderRadioM" value="genderMale" (click)="onFilter('crewGender', 'M')">
            Male
  </label>
</div>
```

This is then the onFilter method

```
constructor(private crewService: CrewService) {}

onFilter(myType, myParam) {
    this.crewFilter = this.crewService.updateFilter(myType, myParam);
}
```

which makes a call to the 'crewService' service to update the filter array with the new values.

This is the extract from the crewService that handles this.

**Firebase Service handler (CrewService)**

```
updateFilter(myType, myParam){
  this.crewFilter[myType] = myParam;
  return this.crewFilter;
}
```

You can see that the crewFilter array simply holds a list of key:value pairs for all filters.  Then the CrewService service implements a method that takes the filter array and uses it as a filter against the AngularFire list that I call up and eventually generates it as a FireBaseListObservable.

```
@Injectable()
export class CrewService {
  private crewFilter:any[] = [];
  crews:FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire) {}

  getCrews() {
  this.crews = this.af.database.list('/crew').map(items => {
  const filtered = items.filter(item => {
    let match:boolean = true;
    for (let i in this.crewFilter) {
      if(this.crewFilter[i] !== 'A') {
        if (item[i] !== this.crewFilter[i]) match = false;
      }
    }
    return match;
  });
  return filtered;
}) as FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
```

so far. so good. This successfully filters the Firebase list according to all filters (ignoring the A's).  Then in the component template, it displays the list, I use the standard ngFor loop to parse them out.

**List Component**

```
  <div *ngFor="let crew of crews | async; let i = index" class="crewsummary row">
```

The ts file for this contains:

```
constructor(private crewService: CrewService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.crews = this.crewService.getCrews();
  this.crewFilter = this.crewService.getFilter();
}
```

So that I call the crewService to populate the local 'crews' object.

Inside this component I have also created buttons to cancel the filters (A means all, therefore clicking the button sets the filter to 'A', which is then ignored in the filter):

```
<a *ngIf="crewFilter['crewGender'] == 'M'" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onFilter('crewGender', 'A')">gender: <b>Male</b> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-times"></i></a>
<a *ngIf="crewFilter['crewGender'] == 'F'" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onFilter('crewGender', 'A')">gender: <b>Female</b> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-times"></i></a>
```

again with the TS:

```
onFilter(myType, myParam) {
  this.crewFilter = this.crewService.updateFilter(myType, myParam);
  this.crews = this.crewService.getCrews();
}
```

Because the member list is generated from this component, when I run onFilter() inside the list component, it refreshes the list properly and I get the right results.

This is where the fun begins!

When I apply the filters in the first place inside the filter component, I can make the service rerun crewService.getCrews() to apply the filters, but it doesn't get populated down to the list component.

I haven't been able to find a way to force the list component to learn that the CrewService.getCrews() method has run and created a new version of the list.

Many hours of searching and trying things related to observables and subscriptions etc. have failed and I can't get the list component to successfully "subscribe" to changes in the crews object when I apply filters. (Note that changes made in the database itself are propagated successfully)

So I don't know if this makes sense to anyone and whether there is a reasonably easy solution or whether I've gone down a rabbit hole and need to think again.

Any help gratefully appreciated !!

Thank you

Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to use an observable for the filter, you could compose an observable that combines the latest database list with the latest filter.

The filter has an initial value, so you could use a `BehaviorSubject`, like this:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/combineLatest';

@Injectable()
export class CrewService {

  private crewFilter:any[] = [];
  private crewFilterSubject = new BehaviorSubject(this.crewFilter);

   constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
     this.crews = this.af.database
      .list('/crew')
      .combineLatest(this.crewFilterSubject, (items, filter) => {
        const filtered = items.filter(item => {
          let match:boolean = true;
          for (let i in filter) {
            if(filter[i] !== 'A') {
              if (item[i] !== filter[i]) match = false;
            }
          }
          return match;
        });
        return filtered;
      }) as FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
   }

  updateFilter(myType, myParam){
    this.crewFilter[myType] = myParam;
    this.crewFilterSubject.next(this.crewFilter);
    return this.crewFilter;
  }

  getCrews() {
    return this.crews;
  }
```

You would then need only a single, composed observable. So you could create it in the constructor.

Comment: genius! thank you ever so much ! Works perfectly. Also moving into the constructor feels so much better as well.  Have marked it as accepted, you've saved me a lot of time and pain, thank you again !!!